# Docker Compose PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I am new to docker and was just testing it on my nodejs-nginx-vite project.
I am using self signed certificates for https request and it is working flawlessly. First I containerised all 3 individually and ran the docker containers simultaneously which were functioning as required then I created a docker compose file but now my node js server shows PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR on firefox and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on chrome. I have .key and pem files and api was working for individual containers just not for compose

```
#my compose file
version: "3.8"

services:
  nodeserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    environment:
      - NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - nodeserver

  reactvite:
    build:
      context: client/attendex-web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    depends_on:
      - nodeserver
```

Now what should I try to make it work